# How to prevent users from accessing content?

Tags: users

Newbie doing tutorial.

I want to deny anonymous access to my site.
My Tutorial (not up to date for V7) says unCheck "Access Content" to disallow access.
This permission does not exist (or I could not find it).
Is unChecking "Access Content" the same as unChecking "View Published Content"?

Have I found the wrong permission?

Answer (score 3):

You want to uncheck the **View published content** permission for anonymous user. So yes you have found the right permission.